# Mapping Up/Down arrow keys in bash

Tags: bash, keymap

I want to map my `Up/Down arrow keys` in bash to `Alt+j/Alt+k` as I don't want to move my hands to the arrow keys when I choose previously executed commands using `Up/Down arrow keys`.

Using vi mode in bash is not an option because I don't want to press `Esc` every now and then while using bash. (as I am not accustomed to doing that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.inputrc` file, creating it if it doesn't exist:

```
"\ej": previous-history
"\ek": next-history
```

This will map `Alt-j` to `previous-history` and `Alt-k` to `next-history`.

Note that [by default](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History) these are mapped to `Ctrl-p` and `Ctrl-n` anyway.

Comment: Ok, this is one way of achieving what I want. Now that I know about this, I would like to know how can I remap `Ctrl-p & Ctrl-n` to `history-search-backward and history-search-forward`.

Comment: @shadyabhi By applying what you learned from this answer. Hint: `"\C-p"`

Comment: Where can I see the documentation of the syntax for defining bindings? Googling for "bash bind documentation" didn't take me the official doc.

Comment: @shadyabhi It's in section 8.3.1 of the manual I linked to, with examples in 8.3.3.